# QGIS using similar colors for all attributes in a diagram

Tags: qgis

When I create diagrams in QGis and add some attributes, by default, they all have the same color which is not what I want: I want each attribute to have a dedicated color.

[image]

I've tried to find a solution for this in the user manual and in the documentation of the Python API so that I could autogenerate the colors but I didn't find anything relevant to this problem. As a workaround I can change the colors manually but is there a settings to tell QGis to use different colors from a palette for the attributes ?

If not is there a way to mass-edit the colors of the attributes ?